# How to upload image from path React JS? (without using <input type="file">)

Tags: reactjs, ionic-react

In my Ionic React JS app, I've the path of the image. I want to upload this image on the server from the path.

I do not want to use input type=file as this image is clicked from the camera and I've the path, not the file object.

Any help is highly appreciated.